# Does PyTorch have a RandomState-like object for random number generation?

Tags: numpy, random, pytorch, random-seed

in numpy i can

```
import numpy as np

rs = np.random.RandomState(seed=0)
```

and then pass that object around, eg for dependency injection.

Does PyTorch have a similar interface? I can't find anything in the docs, but maybe i'm missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest thing would be [`torch.manual_seed`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/torch.html?highlight=manual_seed#torch.manual_seed), which sets the seed for generating random numbers and returns a `torch.Generator`. This thread [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/random-seed-initialization/7854) has more information, apparently there may be some inconsistencies depending on whether you are using GPU or a CPU.

Comment: great! thank you - not sure how i did not come across `torch.Generator`. i'll try this out.